# Access services running on PPTP clients by connecting to PPTP server

Tags: linux, iptables, pptp-client

I have a TCP service running on a PPTP client on port 4567, and the same service on another client on port 4568. They do not have public IPs. I want to connect to these services by connecting to the PPTP server on port 4567 and port 4568 from public internet. I won't be connecting as another VPN client to the PPTP server in order to access those services, any internet connected computer should be able to see those services on the PPTP server The PPTP server has a public IP. Can someone point me to any directions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

On your pptp server offer them fixed ip addresses on the same subnet, so they should see each other

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gabor. I am trying to connect to services without joining the VPN.